# How would I print things from a dictionary line by line?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

So i have (below) which cleans up my list

```
def cleanGpaList(gpalist):
    mylist = []
    for i in gpalist:
        b = i.strip()
        c = b.split()
        mylist.append(c)
    return mylist
```

And (below) which sums up the values of keys that repeat. For example ['Bob','1.0'] and ['Bob', '2.1'] and gives me ['Bob', '3.1']

```
def dictGpa(cleanList):
    diction = {}
    for item in cleanList:
        if item[0] in diction:
            diction[item[0]] += float(item[1])
        else:
            diction[item[0]] = float(item[1])
    diction2 = ', '.join(map(str,diction.keys()))
    return (diction2)
```

Now I am trying to write a final function that prints from the dictionary line by line and the keys and the values.

```
'Bob' '3.1'
'xname' 'xnumber'
```

I have this, but it keeps giving me TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
def printCumulative(myDict):
    for x in myDict:
        print(x)
        for y in myDict[x]:
            print(y,' ',myDict[x][y])
```

Answer (score 0):

To print keys and values you can use simple for:

```
for k,v in myDict.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: For both answers I am getting, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.

Comment: this means that `myDict` is not dictionary. You must be overwriting it somehow with a string.